# Bouncy Castle jar confusion?

Tags: maven, bouncycastle

This class is deprecated:

http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/jce/PKCS10CertificationRequest.html

but when I download this far form the [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.50)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.50</version>
</dependency>
```

There is no `org.bouncycastle.pkcs` there.

Where can I get the latest jar (and the sources)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1.50` or sometimes `150` is the latest release.

The deprecation notes:

> **Deprecated.**
>
> use classes in org.bouncycastle.pkcs.

If you take a close look you will see that this class was moved to a different package: [PKCS10CertificationRequest](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/pkcs/PKCS10CertificationRequest.html)

You will need the following dependency to access that class:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.50</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks! It looks like a good project but not so stable (APIs change a lot) and the documentation is quite lousy. But beggars can't be choosers.